# How should I connect my new light fixture to three bundled whites?

Tags: wiring

Old ceiling light fixture had three bulbs. There are one black and three white wires in box. Whites are twisted together. Do I wire the one white to the connected three whites?

Comment: The usual question is "how was it wired before?" The answer to your question is "probably", but it's hard to say from what you've provided. I'm not sure how the wire count can be true, though. Blacks and whites usually match.

Comment: Sometimes wires get covered with paint or texture.  Double check your wire count because 3 white and one black is an odd combo.

Comment: I suspect there are 2 more blacks pushed into the back of the box.  OP is speaking of the wires he is forced to interact with because the old lamp went to them:  the single black for the switched hot, and the clump of neutrals.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?